# Using multiple AppModules with UpgradeAdapter

Tags: angularjs, angular

We have an AngularJS 1.5.x application and other teams develop few Angular 2 components. We integrate the Angular 2 component by downgrading it. For doing this we use UpgradeAdapter with forwardRef to AppModule. But now I have a second component. How do I use that one? Do I need to create multiple adapters? If so how do I bootstrap the AngularJS application? Here is the code I use with a single component:

```
        var adapter = new upgrade_1.UpgradeAdapter(core_1.forwardRef(function () { return app_module_1.AppModule; }));
        myApp.directive('test', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(dist_1.TestComponent));
        adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['testApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Created a parent module with both the app modules, and used the parent module in the UpgradeAdapter. Only change we have to do is to make sure the module names are unique.